# show inequality holds for all positive reals

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $\displaystyle a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ be positive real numbers and we know that $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=a_1$

Show that:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i^3}{a_{i+1}^2} \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i^2}{a_{i+1}} $

I think applying Cauchy-Schwarz may be helpful but I haven't figure it out yet.

Comment: $a_{n+1}=a_1$? a typo?

Comment: noo that's good

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a_i^2}{a_{i+1}}\right)^2 \leqslant \left( \sum_{cyc} a_i \right) \left( \sum_{cyc} \frac{a_i^3}{a_{i+1}^2} \right)$$

So it is enough to show that
$$\sum_{cyc} a_i  \leqslant \sum_{cyc} \frac{a_i^3}{a_{i+1}^2}$$
which follows easily from Rearrangement Inequality with the vectors $(a_i^3)$ and $\left(\dfrac1{a_i^2} \right)$ which are oppositely arranged.